# Polynomial and simple contrasts for anova

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, polynomial, contrasts

Im wondering if anyone can help me.

Im trying to do a 2x16 repeated measures ANOVA with two conditions across 16 timepoints.

The main effect of time came out as significant and I was interested in doing a polynomial contrast to address the data trend.

When I input the data into SPSS, linear and quadratic trends were significant but cubic wasn't. However underneath this data I have significance from 'order 4' up until 'order 15'. What do these mean?

Also, I'm not sure how to address how the trend changes....can I conduct a simple contrasts afterward to address how the scores of each timepoint are different from the previous to address how the trend changes?

Thank you